# What should the "i"/category be in this for loop and how can I ensure it is in my working directory?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am running a web-scraping project and running into some difficulty using the urls for search results from an initial scrape to scrape information from the search results themselves.

My first loop provides the back halves of the urls I need, after the / (for example, yelp.com/abd - I have abd), which I have in a nested list. However, when I summarize that nested list, like so:

```
profile_url_lst <- list()
for(page_num in 1:73){
  main_url <- paste0("https://www.theeroticreview.com/reviews/newreviewsList.asp?searchreview=1&gCity=region1%2Dus%2Drhode%2Disland&gCityName=Rhode+Island+%28State%29&SortBy=3&gDistance=0&page=", page_num)
  html_content <- read_html(main_url)
  profile_urls <- html_content %>% html_nodes("body")%>% html_children() %>% html_children() %>% .[2] %>% html_children() %>% 
    html_children() %>% .[3] %>% html_children() %>% .[4] %>% html_children() %>% html_children() %>% html_children() %>% 
    html_attr("href")
  
  profile_url_lst[[page_num]] <- profile_urls
Sys.sleep(2)
}
profile_url_lst
profiles <- cbind(profile_urls)
profiles
```

I only receive the urls from the last page of results.

I pasted the domain name to those urls with paste0, which worked fine, but I then encounter another problem. When I use the variable name in a for loop, R returns "variable name is not in your working directory).

```
complete_urls <- paste0('https://www.theeroticreview.com', profiles)
complete <- cbind(complete_urls)
complete
TED_lst <- list()
for(complete_urls in 1:73) {
  html_content1 <- read_html('complete_urls')
  TED <- html_content1 %>% html_nodes("'") %>% html_text()
  TED_lst[i] <- TEDs
Sys.sleep(2)
```

How do I paste the domain name to all the collected urls and bind them, and what should the category be in the for loop?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Difficult to diagnose the issue from your code, but I don't think `complete_urls` should be in quotes for `read_html()`. I'd try to work within a data frame using `dplyr` rather than appending to a list using loops.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you intend to read_html from each url within complete_urls you want to avoid overwriting that variable by using it as the loop variable; as well as referencing it as a string literal. You could instead seq_along the items and index in. Here I print rather than read_html

```
complete_urls <- c('A', 'B')

for(i in seq_along(complete_urls)){
  print(complete_urls[[i]])
}
```

It is probably better to write a custom function to apply to each url and pass that into a tidyverse function/possibly something where you can take advantage of parallel|async running.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by the second part - what would that look like, especially as I am trying to scrape information from each individual profile located by the urls in complete_urls